# In formgroup controls has value but not value part

Tags: angular

```
formatData() {
    if (this.createFormGroup) {
    console.log(this.createFormGroup)      
console.log(this.createFormGroup?.controls?.details.get('nameType')?.value)
        console.log(this.createFormGroup.value.details?.nameType )
           const details = 
          this.createFormGroup.value.details as details
           this.detailsData = details
           }
         
         }
       }
```

it's a preloaded value from BE, optionCtrl = new FormControl(null) this.optionCtrl.setValue(this.selectedVals) this.formGroup.setControl(this.fieldName, this.optionCtrl)

the first console.log gives createformGroup where value of nameType is [undefined] but this.createFormGroup?.controls?.details.get('nameType')?.value gives ['romanian'] which is second console.log. When I console.log (this.createFormGroup.value.details?.nameType ) gives ['romanian'] but nameType is having undefined in details. There is any other method to work set the value.

Anyway to assign the missing value here

Comment: How did you set up your form in html?

Comment: it's a  preloaded value from BE,  optionCtrl = new FormControl(null)
      this.optionCtrl.setValue(this.selectedVals)


this.formGroup.setControl(this.fieldName, this.optionCtrl)

Answer (score 0):

Use getValue and setValue or patchValue. See the [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl)

In this way, you makes angular check the validators, show the value in an input,...

If only change the value, "only change the value".

Both admit the "dot notation".

```
console.log(this.createFormGroup.get('details.nameType').value)
//or
console.log(this.createFormGroup.value.details.nameType)
```

You can use

```
this.createFormGroup.setValue('details.nameType','myNameType')

//or 

//if your details FormGroup only have an unique FormControl "nameType"
this.createFormGroup.setValue('details',{nameType:'myNameType'})

//if your details FormGroup have several FormControls
this.createFormGroup.patchValue('details',{nameType:'myNameType'})
```

See that the first is "reach" the FormControl, after use setValue